# Copy column and replace in another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace, copy

I got this table

| title | image |
| --- | --- |
| this is an example | <img data-largesrc="example.com/image.jpg"'> |

How can i copy the value of title column to image column and replace data-largesrc with `alt="this is an example" data-largesrc`

So it will look like this

| title | image |
| --- | --- |
| this is an example | <img alt="this is an example" data-largesrc="example.com/image.jpg"'> |

Comment: Simple replace function should work - replace(image,'data-largesrc',concat(title,' data-largesrc'))

Comment: I'd prefer to use `'<img '` as a substring to be replaced...

Comment: Why is that @Akina? What's wrong with @Pankaj's method?

Comment: @Asgar The probability that this is a substring in the attributes is lower than that for a substring used in Pankaj's method due to `<` char which is a part of value less often than common letters (something like `<img data-largesrc="example.com/data-largesrc.jpg"'>`).